# How to create a wireless network at home that connects to another router for internet access (similar to a smartphone hotspot)?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, hotspot

Firstly, sorry for any wrong terms I might use. I have very limited network knowledge.

I live in university housing, and the wireless network doesn't have device sharing (that's what IT called it). We have 2 wifi networks: an unsecure one (XXX Guest Wireless) and a secure one (XXX Secure Wireless). If I connect 2 computers to either networks, the devices can't "see" each other. It's like they're not on the same network. This prevents me from using something like Google Nest, Your Phone app, or share my iPad screen to Zoom. All these require the devices to be on the same wifi network.

What I do is I turn on hotspot on my phone while still connected to wifi (XXX Guest Wireless) and connect my devices to my phone's hotspot network. This way, the devices still have internet access, and they see each other on the same network.

My question is, is there a router that works the same way as a phone's hotspot? I have a router, and in the settings page there's a tab that lets me connect to another router wirelessly (it was like a mode that I had to turn on, called repeater or access point or something). I would then connect my devices to my router's network and I'd get internet access and the devices would see each other. The problem is that I would constantly lose internet connection and I'd have to reset the router to fix it. Is the method correct but I just need a better router?

I tried using the hotspot feature in Windows 10 by connecting my devices to one of the computers I have, but I'd rather not depend on that computer being up 24/7.

Appreciate any advice or recommendation.

Comment: First, doing this may be against the acceptable use policy of your schools' network. Second, you basically need to create a new network and bridge it to the existing network, and there are plenty of devices or setups that can do this.

Comment: @music2myear could you please point me to such devices or setups? That is my question.

Comment: This is certainly against the acceptable use policy. Ask IT before moving forward.

Comment: Will do on Monday, but I can't see why. If I'm in my dorm room and my phone is connected to the wifi, would it be illegal to turn on hotspot and connect another device to my phone? They're all my devices and I could've connected them to uni wifi directly so it's not like I'm gaining illegal access.